# Joomla menu is not appearing on any new pages only on old pages

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I recently upgraded my joomla website from 2.5 to 3.4.3 and it was successful. Website is running fine but if i add a new page via menu then it is not showing the main menu on the frontend even the module is assigned to all pages.

Also please note that everything works fine if i turn off the sef and the menu starts displaying on the new pages also but if i turn on the sef, the menu stops displaying on the new pages.

Comment: You should check if menu module is enable for All pages.If not you will have to manually assign module to newly created menus .

Comment: It is already assigned to all pages and menu.

Comment: Explain your problem on this site: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ There is a better chance to find answers.